# Create instance of class from xsd or wsdl

Tags: java, xsd, wsdl

I see project on github (https://github.com/todvora/eet-client) and my question is what should I make to see classes defined in xsd or wsdl files? What kind of technology it is? I have xsd and wsdl and I want to do similar think as author of this project.

Comment: now I see that maeven did it, how can I do it without maeven?

Answer (score 1):

You can use XJC for that. It is included in the java bin directory in the JDK starting from Java SE 6.

Usage: xjc [-options ...] schema file/URL/dir/jar ... [-b bindinfo] ...

For example

```
xjc -d direcory.name.here -p package.name.here schema.xsd
```

You can find more information here [XJC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html)

Comment: Ok, can you explain me one more thing? Where is defined function getPort which is used in https://github.com/todvora/eet-client/blob/master/src/main/java/cz/tomasdvorak/eet/client/EETClientImpl.java ?

Comment: In the SecureEETCommunication class. EETClientImpl  extends that.

Comment: Ofc... Sorry I didn't see that, i thought that its another kind of sorcerrery

Comment: One more question if you can answer, in class SecureEETCommunication i see EETService which definitione I can't find, I think that i should get it form .wsdl file, but how can I do it?

Comment: you can generate classes from wsdl file by using wsimport command utility which ships with JDK.